# Stripping an dynamic url content

Tags: python

I have an Url `http://maps.google.be/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=50.8091411000,5.0198822000&cbp=0,0,0,0,0`

I want to parse it and get latitude longitude from the Url with the keyword `cbll` the values length may vary. i.e i want to get values after the `cbll=` to the `&` .

How do i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string.split`

```
string.split('cbll=')[1].split('&')[0]
```

so it would be,

```
lat, long = string.split('cbll=')[1].split('&')[0].split(',')
```

Example:

```
>>> url = 'http://maps.google.be/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=50.8091411000,5.0198822000&cbp=0,0,0,0,0'
>>> url.split('cbll=')[1].split('&')[0].split(',')
['50.8091411000', '5.0198822000']
```